# Need to get a logic for implementing the tableview sections according to array count

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

My scenario is that I have three different types of arrays that might or might not contain values. I have 3 sections with section headers for my tableview. I am having trouble finding a solution that would be to dynamically set the sections i.e, if one of my arrays doesn't have a value then I don't want to show the section. If 3 arrays have value then show the 3 sections or if any one of the arrays doesn't have value then I don't want to show that section.

Comment: First of all use a struct representing a section rather than an array for better identification by name or id. Then If you are going to remove the last item of one section remove also the section. And vice versa: If you are going to insert an item and there is no corresponding section insert also the section. This is more efficient than a lot of checks in `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRows`.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the comment but I didn't get you correctly. I have 3 arrays, in which every array is of different type. Could you help me with an example?

Comment: show your tried code initally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numberOfSections will be the number of arrays. And the numberOfRowsInSection will be the count of each arrays for that section in your tableViewDataSource.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if section == 0 {
        return array1.count
    } else if section == 1 {
        return array2.count
    } else {
        return array3.count
    }
    
}
```

If there are no items in an array, then the rows will be zero for that section.

Comment: I need to hide the section also if there is no array count

Comment: If you don't have a section header, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I do have section headers

Comment: If you don't have data in a section, set the header height to zero, or display the section header only when the section items are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
// Create enum for simplifying the implementation.

enum SectionType{
case type1
case type2
case type3
}

class TestVC: UIViewController {
// create to show sections only when data is available
var sections: [SectionType] = []
// create your array types
var array1 = [String]()
var array2 = [String]()
var array3 = [String]()
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.dataSource = self
    // Add enums to section only when array has some value
    // You can do this when you get API data
    if array1.count > 0{
        sections.append(.type1)
    }
    if array2.count > 0{
        sections.append(.type2)
    }
    if array3.count > 0{
        sections.append(.type3)
    }
}

}
extension TestVC: UITableViewDataSource{
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // only those sections with data wil be visible
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    switch sections[section]{
        
    case .type1:
        return array1.count
    case .type2:
        return array2.count
    case .type3:
        return array3.count
        
    }
    
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch sections[indexPath.section]{
        // return different type of cells if required accourding to the data in array
    case .type1, .type2, .type3:
        return UITableViewCell()
    

    }

}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays can change dynamically (after the view is loaded), you can implement number of sections like that:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  var numberOfSections = 0
  if array1.count > 0 { numberOfSections++ }
  if array2.count > 0 { numberOfSections++ }
  if array3.count > 0 { numberOfSections++ }
  return numberOfSections 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data source should look like this - `sectionModels = [[cellModels]]`
The outer array represents number of sections and inner array represents number of cells in that section.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionModels.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sectionModels[section].count            
}
    
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellModel = sectionModels[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    // Configure UITableViewCell with cellModel
    }
}
```